# Scraping thefreedictionary.com

Tags: python, python-2.x, web-scraping

This scrapes results from thefreedictionary.com:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
from requests import get


def remove_non_ascii(text):
    return re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', text)


def get_soup(url):
    raw = remove_non_ascii(get(url).content)
    soup = bs(raw)
    return soup.select("#MainTxt")[0].select('.ds-single')[0].text.strip()


def lookup(word):
    base_url = "http://www.thefreedictionary.com/"
    query_url = (base_url + word)
    return get_soup(query_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print lookup('linux')
```

**Example**

[image: Example]

**Warning:** this script may fail to comply with thefreedictionary.com's TOS

Answer (score 2):

1. According to [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), `import re` should come first
2. In free dictionary there is only one div having the class `ds-single`. You can simplify your code to search for this div
3. This doesn't apply to your program, but if you want to scrape multiple pages, it's better to use [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests).